# Google Chrome UI lags and freezes a lot when using NVIDIA

Tags: linux, google-chrome, drivers, manjaro, kde-plasma-5

This issue only happens when I am on NVIDIA mode, using Optimus-manager. Almost the whole Google Chrome window lags and freezes, during tabs switching, scrolling through a page, or almost anything I do. None of those issues happen with Intel mode.

When I run `google-chrome` from the terminal, I get a set of random errors/warnings, such as:

```
[15760:15809:0912/103728.868398:ERROR:media_history_store.cc(363)] Failed to create or update the media history store.
[15797:15802:0912/103730.878773:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(963)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[15797:15802:0912/103730.882750:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(963)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[15797:15802:0912/103730.898669:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(963)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[15797:15802:0912/103731.002719:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(963)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[15797:15802:0912/103731.029972:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(963)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[15797:15802:0912/103731.241849:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(963)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[15797:15802:0912/103731.377846:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(963)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[15797:15802:0912/103731.901584:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(963)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[15797:15802:0912/103732.035607:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(963)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[15797:15802:0912/103732.036747:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(963)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[15797:15802:0912/103732.255290:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(963)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[15797:15802:0912/103732.385807:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(963)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[15794:15794:0912/104124.299060:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a no
n-existent mailbox.
[15794:15794:0912/104124.299332:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a no
n-existent mailbox.
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
[15760:15760:0912/112223.140023:ERROR:CONSOLE(0)] "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.", source
: chrome-extension://hnbmpkmhjackfpkpcbapafmpepgmmddc/devtools.html (0)
[15794:15794:0912/112226.732035:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(316)] [.RendererMainThread-0x3b3651c13c00] GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Framebuffer is incomplete.
[15794:15794:0912/112226.732588:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(316)] [.RendererMainThread-0x3b3651c13c00] GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Framebuffer is incomplete.
[15794:15794:0912/112226.735979:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(316)] [.RendererMainThread-0x3b3651c13c00] GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION: Framebuffer is incomple
te.
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
[15760:15760:0912/112854.010751:ERROR:CONSOLE(0)] "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.", source
: chrome-extension://hnbmpkmhjackfpkpcbapafmpepgmmddc/devtools.html (0)
[15794:15794:0912/112858.396243:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(316)] [.RendererMainThread-0x3b3651d24800] GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Framebuffer is incomplete.
[15794:15794:0912/112858.396703:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(316)] [.RendererMainThread-0x3b3651d24800] GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Framebuffer is incomplete.
[15794:15794:0912/112858.400344:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(316)] [.RendererMainThread-0x3b3651d24800] GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION: Framebuffer is incomple
te.
[15760:15779:0912/131741.988510:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(428)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
```

On chrome://gpu I got this log:

```
Log Messages
[74608:74633:0916/153154.369411:ERROR:x11_software_bitmap_presenter.cc(136)] : XGetWindowAttributes failed for window 67108877
[74608:74633:0916/153154.369620:WARNING:xproto_util.cc(51)] : X error received: serial 25316, error_code 9 (BadDrawable), request_code 55, minor_code 0 (Unknown)
[74608:74633:0916/153154.369715:WARNING:xproto_util.cc(51)] : X error received: serial 25317, error_code 3 (BadWindow), request_code 3, minor_code 0 (Unknown)
[74608:74608:0916/153228.345379:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(49)] : MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed attachments: 0/1
[74608:74608:0916/153228.345484:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(49)] : MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed attachments: 0/1
[74608:74608:0916/153228.345560:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(49)] : MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed attachments: 0/1
[74608:74608:0916/153228.345642:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(49)] : MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed attachments: 0/1
[74608:74608:0916/153915.310152:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[74608:74608:0916/153915.310522:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[74608:74608:0916/214714.221299:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[74608:74608:0916/214714.221584:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[74608:74608:0916/215929.724608:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(316)] : [.RendererMainThread-0x2f7a2d44ac00] GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Framebuffer is incomplete.
[74608:74608:0916/215929.727838:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(316)] : [.RendererMainThread-0x2f7a2d44ac00] GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Framebuffer is incomplete.
[74608:74608:0916/215929.737397:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(316)] : [.RendererMainThread-0x2f7a2d44ac00] GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION: Framebuffer is incomplete.
[74608:74608:0916/215954.021207:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(316)] : [.RendererMainThread-0x2f7a2d44ac00] GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION: Draw framebuffer is incomplete
[74608:74608:0916/220008.058684:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(316)] : [.RendererMainThread-0x2f7a2d44ac00] GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION: Draw framebuffer is incomplete
[74608:74608:0916/220034.408424:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(316)] : [.RendererMainThread-0x2f7a2d44ac00] GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION: Draw framebuffer is incomplete
[74608:74608:0916/220043.189388:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(316)] : [.RendererMainThread-0x2f7a2d44ac00] GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION: Draw framebuffer is incomplete
[74608:74608:0916/220045.937984:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(316)] : [.RendererMainThread-0x2f7a2d44ac00] GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION: Draw framebuffer is incomplete
[74608:74608:0916/220525.696125:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(49)] : MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed attachments: 0/1
[74608:74608:0916/220554.409221:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(316)] : [.RendererMainThread-0x2f7a2d44ac00] GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION: Draw framebuffer is incomplete
[74608:74608:0916/220558.096178:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(316)] : [.RendererMainThread-0x2f7a2d44ac00] GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION: Draw framebuffer is incomplete
[74608:74608:0916/220611.742495:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[74608:74608:0916/220618.667367:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(49)] : MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed attachments: 0/1
[74608:74608:0916/220618.723525:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(316)] : [.RendererMainThread-0x2f7a2d44ac00] GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION: Draw framebuffer is incomplete
[74608:74608:0916/220726.109160:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(49)] : MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed attachments: 0/1
[74608:74608:0916/221027.271965:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[74608:74608:0916/221027.272185:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[74608:74608:0916/221027.272353:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[74608:74608:0916/221027.272573:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[74608:74608:0916/221317.184571:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[74608:74608:0916/221317.184862:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[74608:74608:0916/221317.457056:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[74608:74608:0916/221317.457403:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[74608:74608:0916/221318.213239:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[74608:74608:0916/221318.213508:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[74608:74608:0916/221325.047156:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[74608:74608:0916/221325.047475:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[74608:74608:0916/221328.182701:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[74608:74608:0916/221328.183014:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[74608:74608:0916/221336.828021:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(49)] : MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed attachments: 0/1
[74608:74608:0916/221336.828119:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(49)] : MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed attachments: 0/1
[74608:74608:0916/221336.828185:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(49)] : MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed attachments: 0/1
[74608:74608:0916/221813.587792:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[74608:74608:0916/221813.588131:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[74608:74608:0916/221816.806673:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[74608:74608:0916/221816.807032:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[74608:74608:0916/221816.872695:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[74608:74608:0916/221816.873039:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[74608:74608:0916/221824.278854:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[74608:74608:0916/221824.279168:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[74608:74608:0916/222145.960895:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[74608:74608:0916/222145.961188:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[74608:74608:0916/222241.468069:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(49)] : MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed attachments: 0/1
[74608:74608:0916/222241.499350:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(49)] : MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed attachments: 0/1
: MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed attachments: 0/1
[74608:74608:0916/222241.499802:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(49)] : MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed attachments: 0/1
[74608:74608:0916/222241.499844:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(49)] : MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed attachments: 0/1
[74608:74608:0916/222241.499889:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(49)] : MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed attachments: 0/1
[74608:74608:0916/222241.499932:WARNING:ipc_message_attachment_set.cc(49)] : MessageAttachmentSet destroyed with unconsumed attachments: 0/1
[74608:74608:0916/222309.162137:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[74608:74608:0916/222309.162453:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] : SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
```

My system info

```
System:    Host: LEGION Kernel: 5.8.6-1-MANJARO x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.19.5 Distro: Manjaro Linux 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 80YY v: Lenovo Y520-15IKBM serial: <superuser/root required> 
           Mobo: LENOVO model: LNVNB161216 v: SDK0J40709 WIN serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: LENOVO v: 5XCN22WW 
           date: 02/23/2018 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i7-7700HQ bits: 64 type: MT MCP L2 cache: 6144 KiB 
           Speed: 3489 MHz min/max: 800/3800 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 3571 2: 3441 3: 3572 4: 3470 5: 3483 6: 3500 7: 3564 
           8: 3527 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 630 driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile] driver: nvidia v: 430.64 
           Device-3: Acer EasyCamera type: USB driver: uvcvideo 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: modesetting,nvidia resolution: 1: 1920x1080~60Hz 2: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 1060 with Max-Q Design/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 430.64 
Info:      Processes: 263 Uptime: 2d 5h 56m Memory: 15.53 GiB used: 3.52 GiB (22.7%) Shell: Bash inxi: 3.1.05
```